# php mysqli if statement

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am just doing a simple email verification for testing/learning purposes, however I cannot figure out what is wrong. Here is the problem:

The query works.. it updates the field in my table, but it should only do so if it active=0. So basically, it still echo's "success" even if active=1, which it should not be able to query, because its only supposed to grab WHERE active=0 ... this make sense? Here take a look

```
<?php 
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n",
        mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$email      = $_GET['email'];
$activation = $_GET['hash'];

$query = $connection->query("UPDATE users SET active = '1' WHERE
    email='".$email."' AND activationCode='".$activation."' AND active='0'");

if ($query){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}

$connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: im not sure what the question is...

Comment: that is a valid sql statement, it will always return true

Comment: Oh, I guess I was under the assumption that it was true only if it found a result. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query returns true because the query was executed just fine, even if it didn't affect any rows. It only returns false if the query is invalid. You should look into retrieving the number of affected rows. (`mysql_num_rows($query)` for example.)

Also, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string($getvalue)` when using values from $_GET or $_POST in your queries to prevent MySQL injection.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a mysqli equivalent to mysql_num_rows($query)?

Comment: Yes. Just call `$connection->affected_rows` after executing the query to get the amount of rows. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php for more info.

Comment: You're welcome. Please select this answer as accepted if you issue is solved now. : )

Comment: I gotcha bud, had to wait 58 seconds :P

Comment: Ah, alright. I didn't know that. : ) (Never actually asked a question here before. ;p)